# How to use Zermelo API properly

Tags: api

How can i call the Zermelo API? I dont understand it. It's regarding this [API](https://zermelo.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEV/Introduction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use CURL in PHP to get your schedule. You can find good documentation  [HERE](https://zermelo.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEV/Example%3A+Retrieving+a+Schedule)